# Should I switch my Wordpress blog back to HTML 4, or will that conflict with current/future plugins?

Tags: wordpress, html

I have a problem with HTML 5 on my blog. I have made some small tiny changes to the default Twentyeleven theme and they site now blows up on IE6, IE7 and IE8.

Since I've started looking under the hood I've been thinking of re-skinning the site myself in HTML 4 Strict doctype.

Taken from the current markup: isn't all this a whole bunch of nonsense?

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

All this conditional formatting, for what? If the world isn't ready for it, why use HTML 5 at all?

Is there ANY technical reason to do that? Is my site ever going to validate if I take the HTML 4 route? Will I have to override the output of all plugins I'm using?

Looking forward to your comments.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Try to condense it to a single more precise question. Also, those conditional comments have nothing to do with HTML5 (except the last one, which simply makes IE aware of the new elements).

Comment: All I'm really saying is: does it make sense to fix the site to display properly in IE's older versions using HTML 5 or does it make more sense to just make a bullet-proof HTML 4 layout that will display well everywhere from IE6 up.

Comment: @L.: if you’re going to stick to code that works perfectly in IE6, that excludes the CSS property `float`, JavaScript arrays, and roughly a gajillion other things.

Comment: The technique that makes new HTML5 elements render properly in older IEs is also required for the HTML 4 `<abbr>` element, because IE6 didn’t support that either.

Comment: @Paul I actually use float all the time in my IE6 compatible layouts. I'm content if I don't get the same 100% pixel perfect layout I usually get on all the other browsers. I don't know why I would ever need to use Javascript for anything on a simple blog. If I can avoid Javascript and use server-side scripting, I usually do.

Comment: @L.: oh sure, I’m all for leaving out unnecessary complexity. Just pointing out that there are lots of issues with IE6, aside from it’s inability to render unknown elements properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer to this question. It depends on the users (specifically, which browsers they are running) and requirements of the site.

Some sites need bleeding-edge technology or rapid design changes, both situations with which HTML5/CSS3 can help. Other sites are very simple and stable, and HTML5 is entirely optional.

There's no need to use HTML5 just because you can - if you can do everything you want to do in HTML4, use that.

Comment: Well I could just use HTML 4, if only because otherwise about 20% of my site users wouldn't be able to see it properly. But if the Wordpress crowd and the Facebook Open Graph people keep running in one direction (HTML 5 and XHTML which most WP plugins use to render) I'm not sure it's wise to run against them.

Comment: @L.: if you’re writing your own theme, I’m not clear why what anyone else does affects you (I’m not very familiar with WordPress theming though, so apologies if I’m missing something). What small changes did you make to Twentyeleven that made the site blow up in old IEs? Were they actually anything to do with HTML5?

Comment: @Paul Well, what's in it for me that I'm missing with the whole HTML 5 theme that doesn't even show up properly in IE6, 7 and 8? I made my own sidebar as it's been yanked from the current version of the default theme.

Comment: @L.: I’ve no idea what the HTML5 version of Twentyeleven has to offer you. If it doesn’t have a sidebar, and you want a sidebar, could you use another theme that has a sidebar?

Comment: @L. De Leo - HTML5 _is_ the future, but it's not the present. There are a whole range of things you can do to make HTML5 / CSS3 backwards compatible - start with HTML5 Boilerplate, Modernizr, Polyfills, CSS3 Pie. But only if you want to - you certainly don't need to yet, and probably won't for another 3 or 4 years at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

Is it typo? Closing conditional comment tag missed. Add this code after yours

```
<![endif]-->
```

Maybe it will help.
Second. If you have different opening `html` tag for dfferent versions of IE, how do show this tag for other browsers? Conditional comments are understood only by IE. 
More information more help.

Comment: Pasting mistake, but that's not what's breaking the theme.

Comment: Ok. Are you using any specific HTML5 tags? Such as `<header>`, `footer`, `<nav>`? Maybe IE doesn't know anything about them and you need to add these tags? Try to rollback your changes and check the site in IE each time you changing back something. It could help to find what exactly breaks down your site.

Comment: the default WP theme is all HTML 5 so it is using all of the above. I made some small change (added a sidebar) and the menu blows up. I know CSS pretty well but I'm just asking if it's worth fixing or if I should just give up and rewrite the default theme with HTML 4 strict so that also IE6 is served. Since I don't need any of the features of HTML 5 I'd rather not break the site to what still accounts for 5% - 10% of my site visitors (just IE6).

Comment: @L.: I’m not quite clear on why you think rewriting the theme in HTML4 would fix the issue you’re seeing with the menu after you added the sidebar. Also, doesn’t [Twentyeleven](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/twentyeleven/) let you have a sidebar without rewriting it? “Left sidebar” and “Right sidebar” are listed as features.

Comment: +1 @Paul D. Waite.   
@ L. De Leo Why do think that HTML4 will fix your problem? I think you've made some mistakes during adding sidebar. Did theme look good before you had made changes? I think yes. I don't think that Wordpress guys would produce broken default theme. I don't think that wordpress is the best CMS, but do think that they are serious guys.

Comment: @L.: there’s a blog post on how to get the sidebar back here: http://www.transformationpowertools.com/wordpress/twenty-eleven-sidebar-on-single-posts-and-pages It mentions a known issue with IE 6, but unfortunately doesn’t go into more details.

Comment: IE6 is dead. Even Microsoft doesn't support it, so why Wordpress should? http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Not quite! Still counts for 10% worldwide, that might mean that you're ready to give up 10% of potential sales just to use some un-needed fancy stuff that doesn't add 1 thing to the site. WP could easily support it if they gave up on the gratuitous use of Javascript and HTML 5, it would then maybe be up to the theme writers to spit HTML 5 instead to support specific use cases.